# C: Access consecutive series of 12 bits in a char array

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to perform Golay encoding/decoding on a easurement, which is stored in a char array. Thus, I need to access consecutive 12 bits of the measurement, which are passed to the encoder/decoder.

The char array is 22 byte long and looks like this, for example:

```
unsigned char measurement1[22] =
{0xb5, 0x31, 0xc6, 0x51, 0x84, 0x26, 0x2c, 0x69, 0xfd, 0x9e,
0xef, 0xd4, 0xcf, 0xf1, 0x24, 0xd4, 0xf1, 0x97, 0xe5, 0x81, 
0x02, 0xf8}
```

At the moment, I am converting the char array into an array of corresponding bits and pass this to the encoder. However, this approach is quite memory exhausting, since the bit array also is a array of chars - 0 or 1 - with 176 bytes (22 * 8) in total.

Is there a more memory-saving approach, which does not depend on converting the byte array into a series of bits, but rather accesses consecutive 12 bits and passes them to the decoder?

Best regards,
P.

Comment: what do you mean by "memory-saving approach"? Packed array like above is the most memory-saving approach. If you want to extract each 12-bit data value to do some operations on it, do like Jongware below. I cannot answer anything if I don't know the input of the next stage

Comment: which 12 bits do you want to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, off the top of my head, I'm sure you can simplify it further...

```
int i = 0, left = 8, v = 0;

do
{
  v = 0;
  switch (left)
  {
     case 8:
     {
        v = measurement1[i++];
        v = (v << 4) | (measurement1[i] >> 4); // please handle end here correctly
        left = 4;
        break;
     }
     case 4:
     {
       v = measurement1[i++] & 0x0F; // lower nibble
       v = (v << 8) | measurement1[i++];  // please handle end here correctly
       left = 8;
       break;
     }
  }
  // Now encode v
} while (i < 22);
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert an index `i` not to a 1-byte based offset to 8 bits, but to a 12-bit based offset instead. Then it depends on whether you are indexing an even or odd 12-bit triple:

```
for (i=0; i<22*8/12; i++)
{
    printf ("%03x ", (i & 1) ? measurement1[3*i/2+1]+((measurement1[3*i/2] & 0x0f)<<8) : (measurement1[3*i/2]<<4)+((measurement1[3*i/2+1]>>4) & 0x0f) );
}
```

This assumes your measurement array is read left-to-right, i.e.

```
0xb5, 0x31, 0xc6
```

translates to

```
0xb53 0x1c6
```

If your order is different, you need to adjust the bit shifts.

Does it matter that your measurement array does *not* contain a multiple of 12 bits?

Comment: don't assume char is 8 bits wide, use CHAR_BIT

Comment: @maep: the actual width of `char` does not matter here. The array is given as `unsigned char` and contains 8 bit values only. The only operations done on these chars are bitshift and masking -- nothing there to prevent it working exactly the same with '9 bit chars' or even shorts or ints.

Answer (score -1):

You could "parse" the `mesurement` as an 12 bit array:

```
typedef union { // you can use union or struct here
    uint16_t i : 12;
} __attribute__((packed)) uint12_t;
printf("%u", ((uint12_t*) mesurement)[0]);
```

This will print the first 12 bits of your array.

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour due to using the wrong printf format specifier, and using reserved name `uintN_t`, and violating the strict aliasing rule.  Also the layout of the bit-field is implementation-defined